# In Celery Python, output of a task to parallel processing task

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, celery

I have created a task

```
@app.task
def mainTask(msg,nc):
    decryptFunction.decryptFunc(msg)
    if len(decryptFunction.messageJson):
```

I am receiving data asynchronously.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    result = mainTask.delay(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"),1)
```

i need to use output decryptFunction.messageJson in 5 tasks and run concurrently

Comment: Do you mean that you want `decryptFunction.messageJson` to be used in 5 separate tasks but still want `mainTask` to run without stopping?

Comment: yes, that is the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am understanding from your requirement, I would suggest, Instead of making `mainTask` as async you can call the other 5 tasks as `celery` tasks, from `mainTask` i.e,

```
def mainTask(msg, nc):
     decryptFunction.decryptFunc(msg)
     if len(decryptFunction.messageJson):
         response1 = task1.delay(decryptFunction.messageJson)
         response2 = task2.delay(decryptFunction.messageJson)
         response3 = task3.delay(decryptFunction.messageJson)
         response4 = task4.delay(decryptFunction.messageJson)
         response5 = task5.delay(decryptFunction.messageJson)
```

and your `on_message` function as:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    result = mainTask(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"),1)
```

But this is assuming that your other 5 tasks are mutually exclusive and response of one, doesn't affect the other task, because if they are not, you cannot make them async tasks.

But if your `mainTask` is time consuming you can use it as a `Celery` task.

Comment: is it wise to use celery group for parallel processing  task 1 to 5

Comment: I have used it in some of my projects, has worked for me till now.